# How to highlight text in textbox in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In a Windows Phone project I have the following scenario:

1. The user types some text in a textbox
2. The user presses a button which disables the textbox and starts a process
3. Some processing of the text is done and on every step of the processing I want to highlight certain part of the text in the textbox (the text itself does no change).
4. The textbox is enabled after the processing is complete.

What is the right way to do this?

Currently I have tried to set some selection background and set the selected text using the textbox Select method but there is no visual indication of the selection even when the textbox is enabled. The SelectedText property returns the correct selected text but at least in the emulatior nothing changes visually.

Here is the code I use that does not work:
XAML

```
<TextBox Name="txtTest" AcceptsReturn="True" Height="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" SelectionBackground="Red"></TextBox>
<Button Name="btnTest" Width="200" Click="btnTest_Click">Test</Button>
```

Code behind

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtTest.Select(1, 1);
    //on this line SelectedText has the correct value
}
```

I am open to other ways to do this. I don't really want to use the selection since semantically this is not a selection but I felt it was the easiest way to achieve what I want. I may use other means to highlight specific characters for example making the font size bigger. I may also hide the textbox and replace it with a TextBlock that looks the same but I feel like there should be easier way to achieve this.

So what is the right way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a research I found out that the Select method on a TextBox only provides visual indication if the TextBox has focus. The TextBox cannot have focus when it is not disabled so it was of no use to me. The RitchTextBox is read only and the API to select parts of the text is more complex than the solution I used.

I used a TextBlock with the following code to highlight the text:

```
private void SetTextBlock(TextBlock textBlock, string text, int selectedIndex)
{
    textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
    Run previous = new Run();
    previous.Text = text.Substring(0, selectedIndex);
    Run current = new Run();
    current.Text = text.Substring(selectedIndex, 1);
    current.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    current.FontWeight = FontWeights.ExtraBold;
    Run next = new Run();
    next.Text = text.Substring(selectedIndex + 1, text.Length - selectedIndex - 1);
    textBlock.Inlines.Add(previous);
    textBlock.Inlines.Add(current);
    textBlock.Inlines.Add(next);
}
```

When I am processing the input I make the TextBox invisible and the TextBlock visible. When the user is providing input I switch the two. I am not sure if this is the right way to do it and I am open to other solutions but so far this is the easiest I have found.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a single instance to highlight you could use the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties.

If you have to highlight multiple instances then you could replace the TextBox with a `RichTextBox` and indicate highlights by styling it appropriately. This won't allow you to show the highlighting while in edit mode though.

If you need to enable highlighting of text while editing it you'll need to create your own replacement/alternative TextBox.

Comment: I don't need to highlight while in edit mode but the problem is that after using either the Select method or setting the SelectionStart and SelectionLngth properties there is no visual indication of the selection in the phone emulator. Do I need to force refresh in some way? I added code to my question to show what I am doing currently.

Comment: @Stilgar It works for me if I set `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` explicitly, rather than using `Select`.

Comment: I tried this but it seems that the textbox should have focus in order to have visible indication which sadly is impossible when it is disabled:(

Comment: @Stilgar If you need to highlight the text when the control is disabled then you'll have to make your own control which wraps the textbox and then when disabled show a `RichTextBox` (or similar) instead with styling to recreate the selected appearance. [Be careful with light and dark themes ;)]

Comment: I just made the textbox invisible and replaced it with a textbox. See my answer. I couldn't see any value in using the RichTextBox in this case.

Comment: @Stilgar yeah that works. RichTextBox is just my default go-to whenever I need to present read only text with formatting.

Comment: The RitchTextBox API for selection seemed much more complex (with TextPointers and stuff) and the actual text representation seemed more complex at least at first glance with paragraphs and all that. THe text block was simpler to use in the simple case. Now if RitchTextBox supported editing that would be different because I would not have to deal with hiding and displaying the controls but... yeah.

Comment: I've never done highlighting of disabled text so would have just styled the particular bits of text to look highlighted. Yeha, in htis situation your solution looks simpler.